# Knowing the size of Lazy loaded collection

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is there any way to know the size of a lazily loaded collection without loading the collection object(without writing a `@NamedQuery` with `COUNT(*)`) ?

Something like `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` in hibernate ?

Note : I'm using JPA 2.0(EclipseLink)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, size will instantiate the relationship.  You need to issue a query to get the size if desired.